# How to clear ui-select-match stored value in angular?

Tags: javascript

I am using the select and search functionality in my code and I want to reset the selected value from the `ui-select-match` automatically on form submit without clicking on cross button.

I'm using the given code

```
<ui-select-match allow-clear="true" class="form-control-ui-select"  placeholder="{{'select_or_search' | translate}}">
      {{$select.selected.name  || $select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices  repeat="state.id as state in stateList | filter: $select.search | limitTo:maxOptionSize">
      <span ng-bind-html="state.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: `$scope.selected = null`?

Comment: Hey @Phil,

Thanks for reply.. I already tried this one but its not working.

Answer (score -1):

you can use allow-clear="true". I tried and it is working.